# Взять комментированный контент из html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вопрос таков. Допустим на сайте есть какие то куски `html` которые комментированы. К примеру вот так `<!--<div>text</div>-->`

Можно ли с помощью `javascript` взять эти куски и использовать как то?

> Но не надо давать какие то отдельные библиотеки. Не хочу для этого
>   прикрепить еще какую то библиотеку с сотнями строк на сайт.
>
> И еще парсинг с регулярками совсем не интересен, потому что тогда выбранные узлы будут просто `string` и отдельно работать с ними не получится.

Вот примерный код `html`.

```html
<div id="image-container">
    <!--
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/1" width="200" height="100">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/2" width="200" height="100">
    -->
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: используй регулярные выражения.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753384/get-text-inside-html-comment-tag

Comment: @norbornen Спасибо подошло.

Comment: В последний раз где я видел подобное, оно вместо комментария было упаковано в `script` с особым `type`, стандартных обработчиков которого нет. Был собственный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, но в виде строки

```js
function enumDom() {
  var div = document.getElementById('image-container');
  for (var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (div.childNodes[i].nodeType == 8)  // NODE_COMMENT
      console.log(div.childNodes[i].nodeValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
    <!--
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/1" width="200" height="100">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/2" width="200" height="100">
    -->
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<button onclick="enumDom()">Enum</button>
```

Чем парсить такую строку - смотрите сами. jQuery с этим справится.

А зачем такое извращение? Не проще ли эти элементы сделать просто невидимыми?

Если Вам нужно подгрузить изображения, так сделайте так

```js
function showImage() {
  var div = document.getElementById('image-container');
  for (var i = 0; i < div.children.length; i++) {
    var img = div.children[i];
    img.src = img.attributes['data-src'].value;
    img.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

```css
#image-container img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
    <img data-src="https://multator.ru/preview/uximrdanemqi" width="200" height="100">
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<button onclick="showImage()">Show</button>
```

Comment: Невидимые элементы и все что в них есть браузер загружает. А мне это не надо. Мог бы использовать `ajax` но для этого то же большую логику в моем компоненте должен был бы поменять. А работа с элементами с помощью `javascript` это не `извращение`.

Comment: @StackOverflow Извращение - это работать с комментариями как с валидной разметкой.

Comment: Комментарии то же часть `html` разметки, и его валидность зависит от автора. Если бы это было извращением то в `javascript` не были бы столько методов работы с ними.

Comment: @StackOverflow Я понял, что Ваш путь самый правильный, но посмотрите мой обновленный ответ

Comment: А вы почему думаете что часть той разметки всегда должен быть таким простым. Спасибо за ответ. Но я хотел именно то что задал в вопросе. А почему я так хочу это уже другая `история`.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть так?

```js
var text = document.getElementById('image-container').innerHTML.replace(/(<!--)|(-->)/g, '').trim();

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML= text;
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
    <!--
    <img src="https://www.askideas.com/media/17/Cute-Ragdoll-Kittens.jpg" width="200" height="100">
    <img src="http://www.porjati.ru/uploads/posts/2015-05/thumbs/1431621727_1.jpg" width="200" height="100">
    -->
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Ну да но это уже текст, а не `dom` объект. И с ним можно работать только как текст.

Comment: Вы комментарий к первому `ответу` не прочитали.

Comment: @StackOverflow `Ну да но это уже текст, а не dom объект. И с ним можно работать только как текст` - с чего бы это? спокойно вставляется в контейнер

Comment: @StackOverflow почему я должен читать все комментарии во всех ответах, а не делать вывод из описания в вопросе?

Comment: Ну да, а если первую картинку мне нужно вставить в контейнер номер один, а второй в номер 27? Ну вы поняли о чем я.

Comment: Я не говорю что это обязательно, но если бы прочитали, уже бы знали что ваш вариант не устраивает. А так ответ верный. Просто мне не подходит.

Comment: @StackOverflow просто представляете если у вопроса будет например 5 ответов и везде комментарии.. и я как человек, который решит написать ответ почему-то должен читать именно их, чтобы понять о чем речь, а не брать данные из описания в вопросе.. Это же смешно. Вам надо отредактировать непосредственно вопрос и внести туда все исходные данные и ожидаемый результат

Comment: Ну да просто тогда был один ответ. И я спросил не прочитали комментарий.

Comment: @StackOverflow не читал и не читаю)